# Drag a specific row into a new table with jQuery Sortable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to drag a specific row from one table into another table. I see the demo using LI and UL but I'm trying to do it with a table object. I created a JS fiddle to have my two different tables.

I tried different variations:

```
$( "#selected-stock-grid, #stock-grid" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".table-stock-content"
}).disableSelection();

$( "#selected-stock-grid, #stock-grid" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".table-stock-content tbody"
 }).disableSelection();

$( "#selected-stock-grid, #stock-grid" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".table-stock-content tbody tr"
 }).disableSelection();
```

Here is a JS fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3f0u86gL/

It only tries to move the whole table instead of an individual row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more specific on your `selectors`, use the `tbody` element instead the whole table:

[From the API](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/)

> Note: In order to sort table rows, the tbody must be made sortable, not the table.

```
$(function() {
  $( "#selected-stock-grid tbody, #stock-grid tbody" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".table-stock-content tbody"
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

[**Updated Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3f0u86gL/1/)